# array iterator not dereferencable error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdarray

There is a sample code that occurs the error as bellows.
In release mode, it works and prints five '-'.
However, in debug mode, it doesn't work and occurs a runtime error that is 'array iterator not dereferencable'.

environment details :
Windows 7 64bit
Visual Studio 2015 update 2

I don't know why there are deferences between release and debug mode.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

static bool operator != (int * a, std::array<int, 5>::iterator &b)
{
    return a != &(*b);
}

int main(void)
{
    std::array<int, 5> arr = { 0,0,0,0,0 };

    for (auto* it = &arr[0]; it != arr.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "-" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `*b` when `b` is `arr.end()`.  This causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939). You can only use `*` on an iterator that refers to an element of the array.

Comment: Note that while it is true of course that it is undefined behavior with respect to the standard, the behavior is in fact easily explained with respect to the specific implementation. That explanation being that VC++ iterators have checks for things like this in debug mode, and throw exceptions when an iterator is improperly used. And those checks are disabled in release mode.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're exactly right. MSVC supports debug iterator to detect incorrect iterator use. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Overloading operators requires that at least one operand be a class or enumeration type. `std::array<int, 5>::iterator` is just a typedef for `int*`, which is a built-in type. You don't need to overload the comparison operator since the comparisons between pointers are already well-defined.

References:

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#intrinsics-and-operator-overloading

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/iterators.html

Comment: If this was the case, then it would be a compiler error, not a runtime error.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The fact that it compiles in VS2015 is a bug. It fails to compile in both GCC and Clang.

Comment: array iterator may or may not be a typedef for `int*`.  The function is OK in cases where it isn't. There is no compiler bug here

Comment: No, it's not a bug. `std::array` iterators are allowed to be plain pointers, but they are not required to be.